# Поиск перестал работать?

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, поиск

Всегда выполнял поиск по вопросам с параметрами

> [is:q intags:mine closed:no](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3Aq%20intags%3Amine%20closed%3Ano)

Сейчас показывает только вчерашние вопросы. Хотя сегодняшние с моими метками точно есть, и немало...

Я что-то делаю не так или у нас проблемы?...

**Update от 06.11.2017**

Та же проблема...

Comment: alexolut [писал вчера про аналогичные проблемы с android API](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300679/something-wrong-with-tag-view-in-the-android-app).

Comment: У Вас слишком много ответов, система не справляется :) отдохните немного. P.S. другие тоже репу хотят собрать :-D

Comment: @alexolut Как раз моя автоматизированная система, которая у меня браузер открывает, обнаружив новый вопрос на заданные темы - работает (она не привязана к моему аккаунту). Я с ней спорить не могу :) - и так больше половины вопросов просто пропускаю...

Comment: @alexolut За последние 2 часа пришло как минимум 2 вопроса по C++ - я по вашей просьбе уступил их вам... Что же вы не отвечаете? :)

Comment: @Harry так я не для себя просил :) ну, м что такое два часа? Пшик

Comment: @alexolut Для человека, который ждет ответа? вечность :)

Comment: Запулил баг на [mse](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300702/339911).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблему [пофиксили](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300720/339911).

Comment: Огромная просьба - повторите свое запуливание :), а то опять та же фигня творится...

Comment: @Harry добавил обновление в вопрос на MSE.

Comment: @Harry у меня работает (вопросы 3 минуты назад созданные показывает). Вы сортировку выбрали? (по умолчанию relevant стоит, а не newest или active).

Comment: @jfs уже заработало. Час назад отображал только сообщения 7-часовой давности.

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: @Harry они видимо сами сломали, сами починили. Так что не за что ;)

Comment: Ну, вы же их подтолкнули :)